# Would anyone be interested in writing a blog-post about this site?

Tags: discussion, community-blog

Last months post was about [Da'wah](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/2013/08/dawah-conveying-or-conversion/), and the one before that was about [Ramadan](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/how-to-make-the-most-out-of-ramadan/).  This months blog-post is scheduled to be published on the 15th, a Sunday.  The subject of the post will be about this site, the details can be worked out later (in another meta discussion).  It can be about issues this site is facing, it can be about a certain issue this site is facing, or it can be something else.  Currently all the posts on our blog is written by me, so I would like to ask, would anyone be interested in writing this upcoming blog-post?

Comment: I would be willing and happy to do it, if nobody else wants to. I imagine that it might be better if it were written by an actual Muslim, though.

Comment: @Daniel thats great , thanks for showing your concern and your great efforts for this site

Comment: @Daniel Since the blog-post will be about this site, I don't see a problem in having a non-Muslim write it.  We are going to gather suggestions [here](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/810/which-subject-shall-we-chose-for-the-upcomming-blog-post) and have them voted on to work out the details of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would love to, personally.  But it's a very open question whether or not I'd actually be able to get anything done in this time-frame.

I could probably commit to something if you wanted it for next month's (i.e. October's) blog, but given the speed I normally write at and how much (read: little) time I've actually allotted myself for writing lately, I'd be very surprised if I could get anything done for this month.